# Deploy safe rollback producing application error

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, heroku-toolbelt

I am currently having an issue when deployment to heroku, I am using parse with heroku, everything was working great until now. I was trying to integrate sendgrid to my app, but as soon as I deployed the build with sendgrid, I got an application error when trying to access the app server url, so I decided to quit sendgrid for now.

After rolling back to a safe build, I could enter the app server url and the app was working normally, but when downloading that same git version and trying to deploy that same unmodified git I got an error when trying to access the app server, I dont know what to do since I didnt make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please paste the error you are receiving?

So we can try to help you.

Anyway there are solutions like https://www.back4app.com that provides easy and quickly hosting of parse server, including sendgrid support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I found the answer, when I delete the cloud code in my main.js, the app is back to normal, It seems when deleting the sendgrid implementation I also deleted the parse cloud api or something like that. I will try some fix when I get home tonight and post if I get around the problem. Thanks again